# Windows 10 homegroup, "0x80070035 network path was not found" when accessing shared folders

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, network-shares, home-networking

I made a homegroup with a PC act as a "server". It shared folders to be accessed by another PCs in my homegroup.

A while ago, I updated this "server" PC to windows 10. But the problem occurred that only PC with windows 7 can access the shared folder, if windows 10 PC tries to access, the:

> 0x80070035 network path was not found

error comes up.

These are things that I have tried, but nothing works

- Creating new homegroup
- Enable NetBIOS over TCP/IP
- Turn off firewall
- Uninstall antivirus (Norton Internet Security)

Thank you.